# Covariant Derivatives: what is the difference between $\nabla Y$ and $\nabla _{\partial_{b}}Y$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors, connections

Consider then a the vector fields $\partial_{b}$ and $V$; $\partial_{b}$ are the (covariant) basis vectors and $V$ is a contravariant vector field. With a (affine) connection $\nabla$ we can therefore define two derivatives:

\begin{equation}
    \nabla_{\partial_{b}} V = (\partial_{b}V^{a} + \Xi^{a}\hspace{0.1mm}_{bc}V^{c}) \partial_{a} =\nabla_{b}V^{a} \partial_{a} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \nabla V = (\partial_{b}V^{a} + \Xi^{a}\hspace{0.1mm}_{bc}V^{c}) \partial_{a} \otimes \mathrm{d}x^{b} =\nabla_{b}V^{a} \partial_{a} \otimes \mathrm{d}x^{b} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

My question is: **what is the difference between $\nabla_{\partial_{b}} V$ and $\nabla V$ ?**

Comment: You've given the definitions. The first is a vector field, whereas the second is a tensor field of type $(1,1)$. Once you contract the second one with any vector field $X$, you again have a vector field, namely $\nabla_X V$.

Comment: Therefore is the map $\nabla _{(\cdot)}V$ ?

Comment: Sure, if you identify a $(1,1)$-tensor with a linear map from the tangent bundle to itself.